# How to select an option on cmd with batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file to run a number of commands on command prompt. It looks like below:

```
cd\
cd Client SimulatorTools_1
cd CS_92
ClientSimulator.exe testData.xml < 1.txt
```

After the simulator is run, I have to select one option from list of options displayed on cmd. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

CHOICE command allows user to select an option from the list of options. Take a look at below links

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504(v=ws.11).aspx

Hope it helps